# password encrypt/decrypt

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a users  sql server table and I want to make password encrypted and saved in this table using asp.net. I also want that user can get the password on forgot password and edit profile page so I need to decrypt it as well. Which algorithm or encryption techniques do I need to use ?

Please suggest

Comment: I would suggest you never decrypt your password.  most Password are stored with one way encrpytion (can't be decrpyted) this is a lot safer.  If someone forgets thier password, it is much better to just give them a new one.

Comment: @Limey - "one way encryption"? You mean hashing.

Comment: Hash the password and give user facility to reset password. Use SHA1Managed algorithm inbuilt in .net for one way encryption.

Comment: Do **not** make a password decryptable. Hash it or whatever, but noone - not even you or the user - should be able to retrieve the plain text password. If i register with a website and they can send me my plaintext password, then i know something is wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't encrypt a password into the database - hash it (using a salt).

Being able to retrieve a password is not something you really need. You need to enable people to log back in. Being able to decrypt a password means you may well be allowing people to know the passwords of your users.

I suggest reading [Everything you ever wanted to know about building a secure password reset feature](http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/05/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know.html) by Troy Hunt. It is a full analysis of the problems and solutions for implementing a secure password strategy.

Comment: what about reset password ? How can I reset password If I hash it. I assume hashed password can not be retrieved.

Comment: @DotnetSparrow - You don't retrieve it. You let the user set it to something new. Read the article.

Answer (score 1):

The safest thing to do is to hash the password so that it can't be decrypted - thus no one else will know their password, including you & members of your company.  When a user goes to forgot password - generate a temporary one and force them to reset it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that best way would be to use [ASP.net membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx).